# Mapping a local CSV file to a remote server and reading latest data in CSV for populating graphs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, raspberry-pi, webserver

So currently I have a Raspberry Pi that gets the data from somewhere, processes it, and writes it to a local CSV file. The data comes at irregular intervals and I'm planning on displaying these numbers in CSV onto a webserver, perhaps in the form of graphs.

I did look into fusion charts and they do seem to have a real-time graphing option, which I was able to use. Here are a few concerns: (apologies for dumb questions: not too equipped with web dev)

- Is merely running an HTML file on a web browser basically acts as a webserver? I tried out [Nginx](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md) and all it did was created an HTML which I was able to run on a browser, which I was able to do with the source code from fusion charts that I stored in a separate HTML.
- How would I go about constantly keeping track of the latest data being written to a CSV? In the source code of fusion charts, I see it calls a function to update the chart within `setInterval()` which also takes an argument to set the frequency. With this, I could maybe just use the last line of the CSV while keeping track of the index, so the next data is taken from `index+1` and so on...
- How do I map a local file to a server without me having to manually upload it myself? Just to test, I uploaded the csv file to [something like this on gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guest271314/c4eebf14b4a3cfd36f58/raw/37b82a07ec91e9f35396a23ee7aac26b8dd52c23/file.csv). But ideally, I'd want the local CSV to be mapped to a remote server so the numbers are reflected in real-time based on the local file, and then the JS code will then simply read off the raw CSV file.